# MongoDB doesn't push/increment fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, push

i want to increment a number and push an element in an array with MongoDB, but my code doesn't works.
This is my code:

```
        let users = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("users")

        let user = await users.findOne({"token": data.user})
        let bot = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("bots").findOne({"id":data.bot})

        if(user != null) {
            if(user.likedBots != null) {
                user.updateOne({$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
                console.log("bot a cui hai lasciato like aggiunto!!")
            }
            if(bot != null) {
                bot.updateOne({$inc: {"like": 1}})
                console.log("like aggiunto!")
            }
        }
```

The error:

```
                user.updateOne({$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
                     ^

TypeError: user.updateOne is not a function
```

How i can do?
Thanks in advice and sorry for bad english!

EDIT:
fixed by using this code:

```
        console.log(data)
        let users = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("users")

        let user = await users.findOne({"token": data.user})
        let bots = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("bots")
        let bot = await bots.findOne({"id":data.bot})

        if(user != null) {
            if(user.likedBots != null && bot != null) {
                users.findOneAndUpdate({"token": data.user}, {$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
                console.log("bot a cui hai lasciato like aggiunto!!")
                bots.findOneAndUpdate({"id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": 1}})
                console.log("like aggiunto!")
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: `insertOne` inserts a new document. Use `updateOne` to update existing document.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit doesn't works.
Says that is not a function:
                user.updateOne({$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
                     ^

TypeError: user.updateOne is not a function

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i've added full code

Comment: If you got the solution from an answer, it's a good habit to accept the answer rather than silently copy/paste the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user != null && user.likedBots != null && bot != null) {
    users.findOneAndUpdate({"token": data.user}, {$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
    console.log("bot a cui hai lasciato like aggiunto!!")
    bots.findOneAndUpdate({"id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": 1}})
    console.log("like aggiunto!")          
}
```